# Language text changed to gibberish text while import DB

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wpml

[image]
[image]

Language text changed to gibberish text while importing the Db to phpmyadmin.
But in the DB file have correct language text, and it will changed while importing the DB.
This is an wordpress website and the changed happened in WP_POSTS table.
We have used WPML Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Use UTF-8 when you create a table

```
create table table_name () CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

also use this when inserting into table

```
set [fieldname] utf8; INSERT INTO [tablename] (abc,val);
```

Comment: This doesn't look like MySQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @Aleksandar Stanojevic Dante, i fixed this issue by changing DB collation.